# Sampling without replacement

Tags: sampling, bootstrap, survey-sampling

In the context of statistical inference and machine learning, bootstrapping is used to indicate sampling with replacement (e.g. in the context of Random Forest or calculating population standard deviation etc.)

Is there a word for sampling without replacement? Dropout is used specifically for neural networks for neurons, but is there a single word for the general procedure of taking samples without replacement?

Comment: SRSWOR = simple random sampling without replacement. SRSWR = simple random sampling with replacement.

Comment: If I have to pick one word I would use the term resampling.

Comment: Long time ago, I took a class called resampling. The contents included jacknife, bootstrapping, and another tiny thing I cannot remember. So I think resampling is already married with other one.

Comment: @Michael Chernick just the term resampling is not precise. Someone is always going to ask whether you mean with replacement or without replacement.

Comment: A single word cannot really be precise.  I was trying to pick a word that is a generalization of the bootstrap but does not commonly include sampling n times without replacement because that does not introduce different samples.  But I get your point.

Comment: For the record, dropout is more like model averaging than resampling data. Instead of randomly excluding some data points during each round of training, one randomly excludes some "neurons".

Comment: @eric_kernfeld, "randomly excluding some neurons" is the same thing as randomly selecting some neurons without replacement.

Comment: My point is that neurons are not data. Bootstrapping usually refers to sampling the raw data, not sampling from a set of models. Dropout is a way of sampling from a set of models, while using the full dataset the whole time.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld, it seems that we are arguing semantics. My overall question is: just as we use the term "dropout" by NN to indicate random sampling of neurons without replacement, and "bootstrap" to indicate random sample with replacement of data, is there a term for sampling data without replacement?

Comment: I see. So unlike "bootstrapping", this term should apply in all contexts, regardless of what is being sampled?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld, that is where I am going, although I have never seen the term dropout (or any other term) used like that.